# Is there a security reason for not being able to query localstorage size

Tags: html, local-storage

Per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) It seems there's no built in way to query the available size of `local storage`. Is there a security reason for this? If not then why is this not implemented?

Comment: How would you define it ? With the browser specific space it takes on disk ? Otherwise ? If you have your own formula, it's easy to implement it based on sizes of keys and values.

Comment: Generally there are no space guarantees on how much a variable takes in JS, how big is a 4 character string? How big is an array?

Comment: You can do it with IndexedDB btw (not in a particularly pretty way either).

Comment: @dystroy it seems there are already predefined limits per browser and user settings in megabytes. I don't see why it can't return `max` or `available` space. Which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Also IE actually has a `.remainingSpace` property but it's not cross-browser.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that one, @BenjaminGruenbaum. But was generally wondering why it wasn't available on other browsers. Lead me to think there's a security reason for it.

Comment: Simply put - it was not implemented yet. There is [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139444) in the Chromium bug tracker on it that's still open and there is even a pull request that is ready but wasn't yet merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put - it was not implemented yet. IE for example has `.remainingStorage`. There is [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139444) in the Chromium bug tracker on it that's still open and there is even a pull request that is ready but wasn't yet merged.

I doubt this will get in as browser people *hate* localStorage because of its performance implications (because it's sync). It's [not in the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0) which suggests an aribtrary 5mb limit.

You can calculate it yourself [by pushing bigger and bigger strings](https://arty.name/localstorage.html) and seeing where it fails but that's not a particularly good idea either.